# Assign to object key some type list of enums

Tags: typescript

```
enum StatusesK {
  pending = 'pending',
  verified = 'verified',
  question = 'question',
  completed = 'completed',
  declined = 'declined',
  replied = 'replied',
  reopened = 'reopened',
}


type Status =
  | StatusesK.completed
  | StatusesK.declined
  | StatusesK.pending
  | StatusesK.question
  | StatusesK.verified;
```

Above you can see some type I have ( list of enums , which can be used as status). I've created some object , where each key should be a key from my enums list, check it

```
import styles from './styles.scss'

const style: {
  [key: string]: string;
} = {
  [StatusesK.pending]: styles.pending,
  [StatusesK.completed]: styles.completed,
  [StatusesK.declined]: styles.declined,
  [StatusesK.verified]: styles.verified,
  [StatusesK.question]: styles.question,
};
```

Instead of `[key: string]` I want to use `[key: Status]` , but it says me :

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337)

Is there any possible way to make what I try to achieve , or there isn't possible way

Comment: You can likely just use `Record<Status, string>` but you have not provided a definition of `StatusesK` so ‍♂️. Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mAyn8m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Provided `StatusesK`

Comment: Okay, so you could use `Record<Status, string>` or the equivalent `{[K in Status]: string}`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1yBGw).  I was hoping that you would fix up all the unrelated errors, including the undefined `styles`, instead of having to explicitly mention them myself.  Could you please fix up the example so that the only problems with it are the ones you need solved?  Once you do that and if my suggestion works for you I can write up an answer.

Comment: `Record<Status, string>` - this works for me , thanks

Comment: All right, someone swooped in here and answered.  I would still ask that you fix up the question so that it forms a good Q/A pair for future readers.

Comment: Added what is styles in my case

Comment: Uh, `import styles from './styles.scss'` is an error for me.  The idea of a [mre] is that it should be a self-contained example and not require fixing up.  You could just remove it and replace the code with strings like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2ab8W), for example.  Sorry if I am telling you stuff you already know about Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `[key: Status]` to `[key in Status]`. That would help you to solve the error

```
enum StatusesK {
  pending = 'pending',
  verified = 'verified',
  question = 'question',
  completed = 'completed',
  declined = 'declined',
  replied = 'replied',
  reopened = 'reopened',
}


type Status =
  | StatusesK.completed
  | StatusesK.declined
  | StatusesK.pending
  | StatusesK.question
  | StatusesK.verified;

  const style: {
  [key in Status]: string; //`key` can be any name
} = {
  [StatusesK.pending]: styles.pending,
  [StatusesK.completed]: styles.completed,
  [StatusesK.declined]: styles.declined,
  [StatusesK.verified]: styles.verified,
  [StatusesK.question]: styles.question,
};
```

The difference here is that `key: string` is only referred to a single type `string`, but `key in Status` (`key` can be a name of your choice) will add a union type of `Status` which consists all values in `Status`. You can check the document [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (Thank @jcalz for the link!)

But one thing I'd like to note is that this change is only applied for `type` (not `interface`)

For `interface` (even though `type`), we can have a similar effect with [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

```
const style: Record<Status, string> = {
  [StatusesK.pending]: styles.pending,
  [StatusesK.completed]: styles.completed,
  [StatusesK.declined]: styles.declined,
  [StatusesK.verified]: styles.verified,
  [StatusesK.question]: styles.question,
};
```

Comment: yes , thanks and `Record<Status, string>` also works

Comment: `[key in Status]` is unconventional; this is a mapped type and `key` is therefore a type parameter.  As a type parameter it is conventional to use uppercase single characters (or at least an UpperCamelCase name), like `[K in Status]` or `[Key in Status]`.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you explain what the difference is, possibly with links to the docs for [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

Comment: Oh, actually I personally use it to make it less confusing, the key is still key. Thank @jcalz for the useful reference! I'll add it to the answer to make it clear too :D

Comment: It might be less confusing for *you*, but it's unconventional, and consequently more potentially confusing for future readers, which is who we should be optimizing Stack Overflow for.  I'm not going to edit your answer or ask you to change it again, though (I mean, after this comment).

Comment: I modified my answer to make it better. Hopefully, it will help more people having the same questions :D